# what is the best size to use for an Android application icon

Tags: android

What is the best size to use for an Android application icon? Is it 72*72?

I want to install my application on a high resolution screen (hdpi).

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html) and then [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html).

72 x 72px is correct for HDPI, with the actual content within being 60px by 60px. You'd want to support other densities though to avoid upsetting people with other devices.

Comment: I am using 72*72, but when installed, the application icon has a blue contour around it! other by default installed applications don't have this contour!

Comment: Link us a screenshot.   I suspect your .png's transparency might not be set correctly.

Answer (score 26):

You can also take a look here [Android Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html). It automatically creates icons for Android apps based on your needs.

Comment: This tool is really great. Creates all icon sizes automatically from one image. And very nice&easy Web GUI too. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 13):

To create an icon for different densities, you should follow the **2:3:4:6** scaling ratio between the four primary densities (medium, high, x-high, and xx-high, respectively).

For example, consider that the size for a launcher icon is specified to be 48x48 dp.

This means the baseline (**MDPI**) asset is **48x48** px,

and the high density (**HDPI**) asset should be *1.5x* the baseline at **72x72** px,

and the x-high density (**XHDPI**) asset should be *2x* the baseline at **96x96** px, and so on.

Note: Android also supports low-density (**LDPI**) screens with asset size **36x36** px, but you normally don't need to create custom assets at this size because Android effectively down-scales your HDPI assets by 1/2 to match the expected size.

Similarly for **XXHDPI** asset size should be **144x144** px.

Source: [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html)

Answer (score 1):

Android offer three icon sizes. Please see the following [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html):

Android automatically detect which icon size to be used on which screen. for that use the following code snippet in your menifest file.

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable=["true" | "false"] 
                 android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]    
                 android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]                   
                 android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                 android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]                  
                 android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"] />
```

This [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html) would be helpful:

Answer (score -1):

http://makeappicon.com/ is very good to generate app icons for **both** iOS and Android.